# JavaScript which will add a progress bar before a CSS div is loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, json, dom, preloader

Once the CSS div is loaded, progress bar will be replaced by that CSS div.

CSS div is a dynamic one, it takes some time to fetch the data to be displayed and hence I want to show a Loading bar before CSS is loaded.

```
<div id="'+levelDivId+'" class="mainContainerLevel" style="display:none"> 

<div class="nav-header-top">

// code which will be fetching my data

</div>
```

I want to load a progress bar before

```
<div id="'+levelDivId+'" class="mainContainerLevel"> </div>
```

Progress bar will be displayed for 2-3 seconds then this div will be displayed.

I need a javascript for achieving this.

Please Help.

**Problem Solved**, this is how:

We have a mainContainer div which holds everything.

First we load the "loading" div

`$("#mainContainer").append("<div id='loading_MainMenu' class='mainContainerl' style='display: block;'>

<p>Loading Data....</p> </div>");`

//Data div which takes some time to fetch the data to be displayed comes here

We hide the "loading" div before displaying the data div

`$("#loading_MainMenu").hide();`

Now we append the Data div to mainContainer

`$("#mainContainer #"+DataDiv).append("</div> </div>");`

Thats it.

Comment: What's with **the unnecessary** bold parts **in your** question? StackOverflow isn't a place where people write your code for you; it's a place where people help to debug code you've already written.

Comment: can you display your code

Comment: @RahulDesai I have updated my question. Please help

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I am new to this place. Thank you for correcting me. That wont be repeated.

Comment: @vikramsharma I have included my code.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Javascript, CSS and HTML. Look at the way you have written your ID and the comment. Also inline style? really?

Comment: We are not here to write code for you, unless you show us your significant efforts.

Comment: @RahulDesai Hello Sir, I know how to write comment. I would appreciate if you help me on my actual question. I have mentioned that I am new here, still a learner, so please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initial display property to none  at initial point to hide the div  and the when your data is loaded remove the hide css class by using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
   .hide{
     display:none;
   }
  </style>

  <div id="test" class="hide">

  <div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //use your custom event and replace the name testEvent
        $("#test").on('testEvent',function(){
            $("#test").removeClass('hide');
        });
    });
  </script>

</html>
```

and edit the question so that everyone understand your problem

Comment: This is helpful @Aminul , Can you please help with how to display a progress bar(Loading bar) till the time when CSS div is hidden ?

Comment: here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/NAs3V/210/) with jQuery and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) Progress bar   Customize it to solve your problem Thanks :)